# How do I create multiple instances of Certificate Server on the same Windows installation?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ad-certificate-services

The following URLs describe a new feature of Windows Certificate server is the ability to install multiple instances on the same server.

- (see end of "transcript" link it's a zip file) http://www.digitalsupporttech.com/mskb/896/896733_TechNet_Support_WebCast:_Best_Practices_for_Public_Key_Infrastructure:_Steps_to_build_an_offline_root_certification_authority_%28part_1_of_2%29.htm

> Quote: "Multiple Certificate Server instances on a single physical server"

- http://winintro.ru/certsvr.en/html/cf5622e1-daa9-42cc-8b43-14953e34f8b6.htm

> Quote: "Multiple instances of the Certificate Enrollment Web Service can be installed on a single computer in order to support multiple CAs."

**Question**
How can I actually implement multiple CA instances on a Windows 2008R2 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see anything in either of those URLs to indicate you can have multiple CAs on a single OS install (granted, I only skimmed).  You can have multiple CA related roles (web enrollment, ocsp, policy server, etc).  But I don't think you can have more than one actual Certificate Authority.